# PhoneGap File Remove not working

Tags: javascript, html, xcode, cordova

I am building up a basic app which features PhoneGap pretty heavily as i am trying to determine what it can/can't do. i have gotten to the stage where i am looking to remove a file that has been downloaded on the app, but it won't work. most of the code i've used is from http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.4.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileEntry;

```
    function removefile(){
        fileSystem.root.getFile("readme.txt", {create: false, exclusive: false}, gotRemoveFileEntry, fail);

    }

    function gotRemoveFileEntry(fileEntry){
        console.log(fileEntry);
        fileEntry.file(gotFile, fail);
        entry.remove(success, fail);
    }

    function success(entry) {
        console.log("Removal succeeded");
    }

    function fail(error) {
        console.log("Error removing file: " + error.code);
    }
```

and i have called it using the HTML;

```
    <button onclick="removefile();">remove file</button>
```

is there something wrong with the code? i can't see it.

By the way I'm coding for iOS and using JavaScript, HTML and PhoneGap/Cordova in Xcode.

I'm fairly new to iPhone development so any help would be great thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is slightly off. Try:

```
function removefile(){
    fileSystem.root.getFile("readme.txt", {create: false, exclusive: false}, gotRemoveFileEntry, fail);
}

function gotRemoveFileEntry(fileEntry){
    console.log(fileEntry);
    fileEntry.remove(success, fail);
}

function success(entry) {
    console.log("Removal succeeded");
}

function fail(error) {
    console.log("Error removing file: " + error.code);
}
```

Comment: in the API i put in my question there's a link that says `entry.remove(success, fail);`, is that of any use in my code? Would i put that in my button or somewhere in one of my functions? By the way, thanks a lot for your answer :) xx

Comment: never mind i got it :) thank you so much this was an amazing help xx

Answer (score 0):

Old entry. The API may have changed, but I was able to do it like this:

```
function success(entry) {
  console.log("Removal succeeded");
}

function fail(error) {
  console.log("Error removing file: " + error.code);
}

resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.dataDirectory + 'assets/icons/test.png', function(entry) {
  console.log(entry);
  entry.remove(success, fail);
})
```