# Phonegap: Delete the file after read/write

Tags: android, cordova

I am facing the problem while deleting the file from the mobile device after reading/writing to it. I am getting FileError code 6 while deleting the file. It looks like the underlying browser Java is not releasing the file handle. The code looks like -

```
function readFile(){
 fileEntry.file(function(file){
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onloadend = function(evt){
   console.debug(evt.target.result);
   setTimeout(dojo.hitch(this, "removeFile", fileEntry), 10);
  }
  reader.readAsText(file);
 },
 function(){
  console.debug("Error");
 });
}

function removeFile(fileEntry){
 var removeSuccess = function(entry){
  console.debug("remove success");
 }
 var removeFailure = function(){
  console.debug("Remove failed");
 }
 fileEntry.remove(removeSuccess, removeFailure);
}
```

Any help on this, will be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14962974/phonegap-file-remove-not-working  Try this :9

Comment: Thanks @Daniel. I tried it, but no luck.